# CSS3/jQuery Flip Down animation

Tags: jquery, css, html, animation

I saw a very elegant and neat animation on this site:

http://adam.co/

Notice how the 'I like making great ideas happen' comes into view. I was trying to figure out how to do that.

Could someone guide me on how to produce a similar effect for my website?

Comment: Take a look at jQuery's `animate`: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: It's implemented in JQuery..

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's only CSS3 transitions from what I can see in the inspector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is fairly simple without libraries etc.. it can pretty much be done with just css3.

apply a 'loaded' class or something when the page loads and just define an animation to animate the width (or scaleX) and the background positions.

```
@-webkit-keyframes flip-in {
    0%{
         background-position: 5px -80px;
        -webkit-transform:scaleX(0);
    }
    50% {
         background-position: 5px -80px;
        -webkit-transform:scaleX(1);
    }
    100% {
         background-position: 5px 5px;
    }        
}
.loaded #text-block {
    -webkit-animation-name: flip-in;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.75s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
```

Take a look (I only put the webkit styles in for the example, so use chrome or safari):

http://jsfiddle.net/adamco/gUju4/

The staggered effect is simple enough too. You can reuse the same animation and just increase the duration a bit for each one.

http://jsfiddle.net/adamco/NGL4u/